# created_at date syntax problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following piece of code:

```
humans = user.humans.joins(:human_logins).where(human_logins_count: 10).group('humans.id').having('MAX(human_logins.created_at) >= ?', Date.today() - schedule.value.day)
```

The problem with this is the `created_at) >= ?`segment as if my date is equal to 7 days ago, it will find the records that were made in the last 7 days, as opposed to finding the records that were created literally 7 days ago, not 6, not 9, exactly 7 days ago.

How can I make it so that its finding records created exactly 7 days ago? I was thinking of using something like `("? <= created_at AND created_at <= ?", schedule.value.days.ago.beginning_of_day, schedule.value.days.ago.end_of_day)`but I'm not sure how I'd use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
.group('human_logins.created_at').having('human_logins.created_at = ?', Date.today() - 7)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "human_logins.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function      
LINE 1: ...human_logins_count" = 5 GROUP BY humans.id HAVING human_logi...

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "humans.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "humans".* FROM "humans" INNER JOIN "human_logins" ON...

Answer (score 0):

`.having(created_at: schedule.value.days.ago.beginning_of_day.. schedule.value.days.ago.end_of_day )`